# Why doesn't my conditional Branch and Link Statement work?

Tags: assembly, arm, microcontroller, cortex-m, msp432

I am relatively new to the world of ARM so I apologize if I am missing something obvious. For some context, this code is being executed on a microcontroller based on the ARM Cortex-M4F.

When running this code I expected the branch & links with conditional statements to be run if certain conditions were met **duh**. But, what *actually* happens is that after the first compare, regardless of the state of the PSR flags, both KURUMA and SHUKAKU are branched to.

Now I have been able to get the correct conditional branches to work, if I remove the link part of the branch & link command.

How do I get the branch & link to work with a conditional statement, that is **actually** dependent on the PSR flags?

Thank you

````
    .text
    .align 2
    .global main
;
; ------------------------------

main:

    MOV R1, #5
    MOV R0, #1

    BL MATATBI
    NOP
    B main

MATATBI:
    PUSH{LR}
    CMPS R1, R0;
    BLHI KURUMA; branch & link if R1 is higher, unsigned,[C=1, Z=0] than r0 to kuruma
    NOP
    CMPS R1, R0;
    BLLO SHUKAKU; branch & link if R1 is lower, unsigned,[C=0] than r0 to shukaku
    NOP
    POP{LR}
    BX LR

KURUMA:
    ADD R1, #7
    BX LR

SHUKAKU:
    SUB R1, #4
    BX LR
hang_forever:
        nop
      B   hang_forever
;
; ------------------------------

    .end

; ------------------------------------------------------------```
````

Comment: Did you single step through your code to watch the flags?

Comment: what assembler are you using?  gnu assembler?...nope, that complains, ARM?

Comment: duh, with those comments that is definitely not gnu as for arm.

Comment: bllo and blhi are not valid thumb (cortex-m) instructions right?  need an IT block?  please show the disassembly of your code as shown.

Comment: so.s:17: Error: thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block -- `blhi KURUMA'
so.s:20: Error: thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block -- `bllo SHUKAKU'

Comment: @the busybee I did single step through the code and watched the flags, by the time the BLHI was reached [Z = 0] and [C = 1], which should meet the conditions for the BLHI branch but not the BLLO branch. This still resulted in branching to both KURUMA and SHUKAKU.

Comment: @old_timer I am using Code Composer Studio from Texas Instruments as my IDE but I do not know what assembler is being used specifically.

Comment: @old_timer
The code below only seems to work as expected when R1 <= R0, but when the inverse is true the program will branch to KURUMA, link back to MATATABI, then branch to SHUKAKU. I have been able to get the code to work if I throw in an additional compare and IT block between KURUMA and SHUKAKU.  How do I write this code so that only one IT and CMPS is used?

`PUSH{LR}
CMPS R1, R0;
ITE HI
;IT HI; Uncomment to see behavior described above
BLHI KURUMA;

;CMPS R1, R0; Uncomment to see behavior described above
;IT LS
BLLS SHUKAKU;
NOP
POP{LR}
BX LR`

Comment: without seeing the machine code we cant help

Comment: I think you answered one of your own questions.  You can use branch in the it blocks from one compare.  those branches can go to labels that then do a branch link .

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the BL (Branch and Link) instructions (BLHI and BLLO). These are intended to perform a function call only if certain conditions are met (based on the PSR (Program Status Register) flags set by the CMPS instruction).

Unlike the BHI and BLO, BL instructions will always execute the branch and update the LR (Link Register) regardless of the condition. This means that in your code both KURUMA and SHUKAKU are being called unconditionally. You need to seperate these instructions to make sure they only occur when the conditions are actually met.

```s
MATATBI:
    PUSH {LR}
    CMPS R1, R0
    BHI KURUMA_COND
    BLO SHUKAKU_COND
    POP {LR}
    BX LR

KURUMA_COND:
    BL KURUMA
    B EXIT_MATATBI

SHUKAKU_COND:
    BL SHUKAKU
    B EXIT_MATATBI

EXIT_MATATBI:
    POP {LR}
    BX LR

KURUMA:
    ADD R1, #7
    BX LR

SHUKAKU:
    SUB R1, #4
    BX LR
```

Comment: In the OP's attempt, `KURUMA` can modify R1 before the second compare, potentially making it also true (if `add r7, #1` wraps around from a high unsigned number to near zero).  Your optimization to one compare and dispatch is valid if we know `r1 < 2^32 - 7`